# Convert hex value to unicode character

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert the hex value `1f600`, which is the smiley emoji to its character representation by:

```
String.fromCharCode(parseInt("1f600", 16));
```

but this just generates a square symbol.

Comment: do your font support unicode?

Comment: Yes, it's running in Chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most emojis require two code units, including that one. `fromCharCode` works in code units (JavaScript's "characters" [are UTF-16 code units](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-string-value) except invalid surrogate pairs are tolerated), not code points (actual Unicode characters).

In modern environments, you'd use `String.fromCodePoint` or just a Unicode *codepoint* escape sequence (`\u{XXXXX}` rather than `\uXXXX`, which is for code units). There's also no need for `parseInt`:

```js
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(0x1f600));
console.log("\u{1f600}");
```

In older environments, you have to supply the surrogate pair, which in that case is 0xD83D 0xDE00:

```js
console.log("\uD83D\uDE00");
```

...or [use a polyfill for `fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint).

If for some reason you don't want to use a polyfill in older environments, and your starting point is a code point, you have to figure out the code units. You can see how to do that in MDN's polyfill linked above, or here's how [the Unicode UTF-16 FAQ](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-3) says to do it:

> Using the following type definitions
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned int16 UTF16;
> typedef unsigned int32 UTF32;
> ```
>
> the first snippet calculates the high (or leading) surrogate from a character code C.
>
> ```
> const UTF16 HI_SURROGATE_START = 0xD800
> UTF16 X = (UTF16) C;
> UTF32 U = (C >> 16) & ((1 << 5) - 1);
> UTF16 W = (UTF16) U - 1;
> UTF16 HiSurrogate = HI_SURROGATE_START | (W << 6) | X >> 10;
> ```
>
> where X, U and W correspond to the labels used in Table 3-5 UTF-16 Bit Distribution. The next snippet does the same for the low surrogate.
>
> ```
> const UTF16 LO_SURROGATE_START = 0xDC00
> UTF16 X = (UTF16) C;
> UTF16 LoSurrogate = (UTF16) (LO_SURROGATE_START | X & ((1 << 10) - 1));
> ```

Comment: That was it. I was missing the 0x and should have used fromCodePoint instead of fromCharCode. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses UTF-16, so instead of `U+1F600` you need to get `U+D83D U+DE00` - that is, `String.fromCharCode(0xd83d, 0xde00)`

Note that you can use `0x####` instead of `parseInt("####",16)`.

---

To convert a UTF-8 position to its UTF-16 equivalent, here's the steps:

```
var input = 0x1f600;
var code = input - 0x10000;
var high = (code >> 10) + 0xD800;
var low = (code & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00;
var output = String.fromCharCode(high, low);
```

Comment: So how do I go from 1f600 to U+D83D U+DE00?

Comment: @AndroidDev Got you covered.

Answer (score 0):

use `fromCodepoint` function instead of `fromCharCode`

```
String.fromCodePoint(0x1f600)
```

Comment: Note that this is not available in older browsers, including IE (any version). If this is an issue, you'll need a polyfill

Comment: \ud83d\ude42\ud83d\ude42\ud83d\ude42 not working  for me?