# Is there a Javascript way to iterate over non-ASCII, Unicode characters?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I read a couple of articles on Unicode and emojis but I haven't been able to get what I need. 
I cannot figure out if I can use Javascript to iterate over Unicode characters, specifically to display letters/characters for foreign alphabets (Arabic, Hebrew, Mandarin, etc...) (http://www.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt)

What I need : if the first letter of the Arabic alphabet is FE8D (ﺍ) and the last is FEEF (ﻯ), is there a way to loop through those HEX values and display the 28 letters of that alphabet ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert hex value to unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036567/convert-hex-value-to-unicode-character)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a loop with hexadecimal numbers and convert them to a String using String.fromCharCode.

```js
var start = 0xFE8D;
var end = 0xFEEF;
for (let i = start; i< end; i++){
   console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

Comment: So simple ! Thanks so much.

Comment: Awesome answer (:

Comment: Note that this will only work with values up to 0xFFFF (UTF-16) and you need to use `fromCodePoint` for values above that.